# Video of Nikki killing thugs in Episode 1

Tags: heroes

Still going through Season 1, so please bear with me.

When Nikki looks the video camera which was running when she had killed the thugs in Episode 1, all she sees is static. However, when she spends the night with Nathan, the camera footage is fine. Is the static phenomenon explained later in the series?

Comment: Welcome to movies.se! Here's some reputation to get you started!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've seen it I believe the video was actually fine but her memory/interpretation of the video was at fault.

This was because her alternative personality removed the vision of the video in the same way as the memory - to protect her.

Comment: That's definitely interesting :)

Comment: Nice in-world explanation!